# evaluating localDate.now().minusDays(integer)

Tags: java, integer, evaluation

I've been working on a program that stores a series of scheduled events (home made `ServiceRequest` objects) in an xml file (`f`), and when I want to work with them I call a `readData()` method (see below) which loads the `ServiceRequest`'s into `serviceQueue`(an `ArrayList<ServiceRequest>`) and I tag a `null` object on at the end of the file to mark the end of the `ServiceRequest` objects.

As I'm loading the objects in the array, I've been checking the event's date (`LocalDate` object) to remove events more than 270 days old. Now here's my issue: immediately after changing the integer 270 to 180 to try and track less data, the majority of events got deleted(i.e. current events that shouldn't have been, like all of today's etc...). It was literally the only thing I changed, and as soon as I switched back to 270 and recovered the events from a backup, everything went back to normal. 210 also seemed to cause my evaluation to fail as well.

Not sure what I'm missing, maybe something about how `LocalDate.now().minusDays(XXX)` would be evaluated? I can include more of my code if needed, but this was the only thing I changed and the method is pretty basic:

```
public static void readData() {
    serviceQueue.clear();
    try {
        Boolean complete = false;
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
        ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(reader);
        while(complete != true) {   
            ServiceRequest test = (ServiceRequest)in.readObject();      
            if(test != null && test.getDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now().minusDays(210))) { 
                serviceQueue.add(test); }
                else { complete = true; }
        }
        in.close(); } 
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
}
```

I use `LocalDateTime` variables `start` and `stop` to track the events date/time so the `.getDate()` method simply returns `start` in a `LocalDate` format:

```
    public LocalDate getDate() { return start.toLocalDate(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datę checking is ok. The problem is setting `complete` to `true` in case the date does not match.

```
if(test != null &&test.getDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now().minusDays(210))) { 
            serviceQueue.add(test); }
            else { complete = true; }
```

Try the code below:

```
if(test != null) { 
     if (test.getDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now().minusDays(210)) {
        serviceQueue.add(test);
     }
}
else { 
  complete = true; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It was triggering the else statement when test == null the way I wrote it! That's certainly it! Thanks again